# Plan a circuit to convert a 4 digits binary number to two's complement

Tags: switches

I need to plan a circuit that will convert $$-\{Y_3,Y_2,Y_1,Y_0\}$$
To it's two's complement show
$$\{S_3,S_2,S_1,S_0\}$$

I think the question is undefined well since 0 is not unique and since converting a 4 bits negative number to two's complement requires 5 bits and I only have room for 4 bits.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: A 4-bit signed integer is limited from -8 to +7. 0 only has one unique binary equivalent value 0000. If indeed you wanted to expand your range of values to -16 to +15, you need to use 5-bit two's complement.

Comment: XOR the MSB with the most negative 2's complement value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "two's complement" is just a one's complement followed by a increment.  For example:

0101   original
1010   one's complement
1011   plus 1

The orginal was 0101, which is 5, and the result is 1011, which is -5 as expected.  Put another way, it takes 5 increments to make the result 0.

Comment: Edit: Am I not limited to less values than I could possibly get by 4 unsigned bits? How do I treat the ones I can not convert? As 'Don't Care'?

Comment: @Quaker: No, 4 bits give you 16 different values no matter how you interpret them.  If you interpret them as unsigned integers, then you have values in the range 0 to 15.  If two's complement signed integers, then -8 to +7.  Either way there are 16 values.

Comment: yeah but if my input is let's say -{1,1,1,1} which is -15, how do I convert it to two's complement? Isn't it an illegal input which should cause a 'don't care'?

Comment: @Quaker: 1111 is -1, not -15.

Comment: I don't get it, 1111 in binary is 15, not -15 and not -1. If I want to convert -{1111} which is -{15} in decimal to twos complement I am not able to do so. What am I missing?

Comment: I was told that the Y3 Y2 Y1 Y0 number is a normal binary number, not in twos complement...

Comment: @Quak: 1111 is 15 if you consider it a unsigned integer, and -1 if you consider it a signed (two's complement) integer. Other than that, I can't comment because I don't know what your strange notation is supposed to mean.